# Is it possible within SFDC to identify which reports are using a specific object?

Tags: reports-folder

Is it possible within SFDC to identify which reports are using a specific object?  I would like to obsolete the reports but don’t know how to identify short of looking up each individual report

Comment: Shruti, I am not sure about admin process, but I believe a developer can do this by exporting only reports in eclipse IDE and then search in all XMLs for the object name. It can probably make search faster than manually finding in each report through Salesforce UI.

Comment: Hi Nitish, I tried with the same thing but we can't find the object through this when we search in XML.